# Compare datetime field with date in django orm

Tags: python, django, orm

Code :

```
start_date = '2017-02-03'
OutputData = Entity.objects.filter(created_on__year=start_date.year,
created_on__month=start_date.month,created_on__day=start_date.day).count()
```

I have data on that date but still I get 0 count in output and I am not getting why. 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

convert `start_date` into python date object then do the filtering.

## Example

```
from datetime import datetime
[1]:start_date = '2017-02-03'
[2]:start_date = datetime.strptime(startdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
[3]:start_date.year ## 2017

OutputData = Entity.objects.filter(created_on__year=start_date.year,
created_on__month=start_date.month,created_on__day=start_date.day).count()
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one thing that start_date is actually a date object still it is not giving the right output. But then I used __contains and passed string date and now it's working fine. Thank you for your help.